# Getting a list of items with Selenium WebDriver gets items with blank text

Tags: c#, selenium

I have code that looks like:

```
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    var primaryAgendaListContainer = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("ul#PrimaryAgendaIdTemp_listbox")));

    var primaryAgendaList = primaryAgendaListContainer.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
    foreach(var primaryAgendaElement in primaryAgendaList)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(primaryAgendaElement.Text);
    }
```

But the Text for each element is blank. I can use Chrome developer Tools and see that the li 's do not have a blank text. I am getting the correct number of elements but the Text is not correct.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `primaryAgendaElement.GetAttribute("innerText")`, and let me know what that returns. Also, the ***relevant HTML*** would be nice to work from.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there's another tag between the LI and the text.

try to change the code to do this, and tell me the result.

```
var primaryAgendaList = primaryAgendaListContainer.FindElements(By.XPath("//li/*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetAttribute("innerHTML")` on your element from which you need the text. That should to do the retrieval fine.